# Did anyone tried installing Oracle weblogic & Soa on K8s

Tags: kubernetes, weblogic, soa

Need some suggestions & tips, Please let me know if anyone build the infrastructure on K8s with Oracle Weblogic, DB & SOA (OSB, BIPEL, B2B, BAM).

If anyone build the infrastructure please let me know the benefits & drawbacks. Is it recommended to build it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you follow best practices; do not install these on Kubernetes. Kubernetes is very good at for micro-services and stateless applications. Of course Kubernetes support stateful applications like cassandra / nodejs ..etc applications you have a chance to deploy applications on Kubernetes using StatefullSets. Kubernetes treats statefull sets different than other resource objects. A StetfullSet Pod is always scheduled on the same machine as long as you do not delete them.Please take a look at the link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/ You can deploy stateful applications on Kubernetes using the link above

- https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/weblogic-on-kubernetes,-try-it
- https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/automatic-scaling-of-weblogic-clusters-on-kubernetes-v2

We ran weblogic applications on docker swarm but not on kubernetes. All the configuration on kubernetes for stateful applications is pretty easy compared to docker swarm.